# SQL: Update hundreds of rows based on a Unique ID

Tags: sql

I imagine this is a relatively straightfoward/common question but I'm having a little trouble finding an elagant solution to this on S/O.

Basically I have an excel sheet with just two columns from a DB table, one being the unique IDs for the entities and the other being the rows I actually have to update for said unique IDs. E.g:

```
Table has rows
ID, Name, Place, DOB, Hair Colour
I have an excel with two columns
ID, DOB
```

The object is to update hundreds of DOB with new unique values based on the ID in that excel matching what is in the table. Some sort of join statement maybe.

Each update is a distinct date, so doing a blanket update statement a la;

```
Update c
set c.date = 1/01/2001
from tableName c
Where c.Unique_Ids in (
List of comma separated IDs)
```

....isn't going to work really.
The dates in question are distinct to their IDs, bar writing hundreds of individual update statements the simple answer is eluding me. 
Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: What are you trying to change regarding the dates? Please give enough of an example so we can see why the above query doesn't work for you.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is non-standard SQL). Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using

Comment: You can try this

`Update c
set c.date = 1/01/2001
from tableName c
Where c.Unique_Ids in (select c.Unique_Ids from tableName )`

Comment: Why wouldn't you write hundreds of individual update statements? Sometimes the most straightforward way of doing something is also the best. Excel makes it easy to do; just put something like `update table set column1 = A1 where column2 = B1` into cell C1 and drag the formula down for the rest of your data. Boom, hundreds of update statements written.

Comment: I've posted an answer assuming you can import the spreadsheet into a table; alternatively, you could use something like OPENROWSET.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would go a long way here. I can't picture what that second column is supposed to be. A key value? A concatenation of the full row?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two data sources together assuming a 1 to 1 relationship (which I gathered from your description), and set the existing date to be the new date based on that join criteria. This will allow you to set the unique date based on the source data.

```
Update c 
SET c.date = sheet.date 
from table C join excel_spreadsheet as "sheet" 
    on c.unique_id = sheet.unique_id
```

If I misunderstood the criteria, please make sure to clarify the existing data sets.

Read data directly from the excel file -- must be accessible by SQL server

```
Update c 
SET c.date = sheet.date 
from table C join 
(
select * from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Temp\Data.xlsx', [Sheet1$])
) as "sheet" 
    on c.unique_id = sheet.unique_id
```

Comment: I'm going to look into importing the spreadsheet into a temporary table and try this.

Comment: Hey ask, you can also check out open rowset. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Updated with openrowset example. Note that you'd need to modify the database location, sheet name, etc; importing could be cleaner, especially if this is a one-time operation. If you're going to be doing this often, you could parameterize the file name and create a stored procedure with dynamic SQL.